# Python task scheduler file input and output 0x2

Tags: python, windows, scheduled-tasks

I've got a process I'm trying to automate through the Windows task scheduler.  The file is located right next to the script on a subfolder in my desktop.  A mockup that shows the problem I'm running into is:

```
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lines = []

    with open(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\config.txt') as file:
        for line in file:
            lines.append(line)

    with open(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\output.txt', 'w') as file:
        for line in lines:
            file.write(line)
```

When I run this through the command line, the code works fine.  The config file is read in properly and the output works properly.

However, in task scheduler, the program fails to execute with an 0x2 error code.  In task scheduler, I have the tried with the following task scheduler options selected:

- Run only when user is logged on/Run with highest priveledges Run only
- when user is logged on/Highest priveledges not checked Run whether
- user is logged on or not/Run with highest priveledges Run whether
- user is logged on or not/Highest priveledges not checked

I am using absolute paths - as you can see in the above example.  I'm also using the "start in" option inside of task scheduler.

This is seriously annoying me.

Edit: I am using absolute paths inside of task scheduler to both the Python executable and the script.

Comment: Are you running "<absolute path to>\python.exe" with arguments passed as "<absolute path to>\script.py"?

Comment: I am using the absolute path in both of those fields, yes.

Comment: Remove the arguments, so that it only runs python.exe without a script, and configure the task to run as yourself only when logged on. Now run the task manually. It should run the Python REPL in a new console on your desktop.

Comment: Running python.exe opens up the interactive shell even via task scheduler.  I'm not sure what you're getting at here and I'd love some more explanation.  My problem isn't that python isn't running.  My problem is that python isn't performing the open() command, presumably because it can't find the file but only if I run the python script from task scheduler.

Comment: You said that Task Scheduler fails to execute the Python task with an error code of 2 (file not found). That could be from the Task Scheduler not finding the executable, Python not finding the script, or the Python script itself failing to find a file. I wanted to be certain that it's at least finding "python.exe" at the provided path.

Comment: I was slightly wrong on the first case. If Task Scheduler can't find the executable, the file-not-found (2)  error gets returned in a 32-bit `HRESULT` error, and you would have noticed getting 0x80070002 instead of 0x2. Also, for the third case in which `open` fails in the script, unless you have an exception handler that sets a custom exit code, it will just be 0x1, the generic failure code. That leaves the 2nd case. If the Python script itself can't be found by python.exe, then you will definitely see a 0x2 error code in Task Scheduler.